# get id of selected option of datalist object by using data-value

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I want to get the ID (data-value) of selcted option on a datalist object.

I tryed to get the ID by using a Javascript function and use the `this.dataset.value` but i get the result *undefined*

```js
function getIdOfDatalist(divid){
    console.log(document.getElementById(divid).dataset.value);
}
```

```html
<datalist id="options">
    <option value="myoption one" data-value="1">
    <option value="myoption two" data-value="2">
    <option value="myoption three" data-value="3">
</datalist>
    
<input list="options" id="myoptions">
<button onclick="getIdOfDatalist('myoptions');">check</button>
```

What is my mistake? (Code ist simple reduced, JS ist in head `<script>`)

Comment: You said you want to get the id but here you are trying to get the data-value

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here ? Are you trying to get the id on click of the items in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, you've right - I've written ID but mean data-value. If I click on a button, I'll get the ID (data-value) of the selected item of datalist. My Code below allow it, but it feel not right, there must be a better solution...

Comment: Do you want in javascript itself ? Or is JQuery fine ?

Answer (score 4):

If you change the HTML a bit, you can use a method to avoid looping the items yourself. For example:

```js
function getIdOfDatalist(listid){
  var listObj = document.getElementById(listid);
  var datalist = document.getElementById(listObj.getAttribute("list"));
  console.log(datalist.options.namedItem(listObj.value));
}
```

```html
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="myoption one" name="myoption one" data-value="1">
  <option value="myoption two" name="myoption two" data-value="2">
  <option value="myoption three" name="myoption three" data-value="3">
</datalist>

<input list="options" id="myoptions">
<button onclick="getIdOfDatalist('myoptions');">check</button>
```

Notice I added "name" attribute to each item in the datalist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with JQuery.

As JQuery has build-in method called `data()` , It is easy to get the `data-value.`
In javascript you can use something called `dataset.value`, But that has  browser compatibility issues, Apart from that you can use `getAttribute()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {
    var value = $('input').val();
    alert($('#options [value="' + value + '"]').data('value'));
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="myoption one" data-value="1">
  <option value="myoption two"  data-value="2">
  <option value="myoption three"  data-value="3">
</datalist>

<input list="options" id="myoptions">
<button>check</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

with querySelector and input value, the input has a list property that gives you direct access to the datalist element

```
function getIdOfDatalist(divid){
  let value = divid.list.querySelector(`[value="${divid.value}"`).dataset.value;
}
```

Comment: The answer is not really ready, but a good approach. Why not finish it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have only one solution: check input and datalist by using a for loop:

```
function getIdOfDatalist(datalist_id,input_id){

    var datalist = document.getElementById(datalist_id);
    var input    = document.getElementById(input_id);

    for (var i=0;i<datalist.options.length;i++) {
        if (datalist.options[i].value == input.value) {
            // obtains the data-company attribute
            console.log(datalist.options[i].getAttribute("data-value"));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is in my view not the best solution or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getIdOfDatalist()
{
    var element_input = document.getElementById('myoptions');
    var element_datalist = document.getElementById('dl_options');
    var opSelected = element_datalist.querySelector(`[value="${element_input.value}"]`);
    var id = opSelected.getAttribute('data-value');
    //id hold the selected datalist id
}
```

```html
<datalist id="dl_options">
  <option value="myoption one" data-value="1">
  <option value="myoption two" data-value="2">
  <option value="myoption three" data-value="3">
</datalist>

<input list="dl_options" id="myoptions">
<button onclick="getIdOfDatalist();">check</button>
```